# Magento 2 get current category Id using registry

Tags: category, magento2, registry

Any one know how I can get the category id using current category registry in Magento 2?

Comment: Refer blogs, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-current-category-data-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have done in your controller maybe you should get the object manager to be initialized by the use of context class in the `__construct` method.

Comment: Hi  i already call construct method in my block class file please check below link for more detail   http://codebeautify.org/alleditor/0b796a   And thanks for help.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. You should not use Objectmanager in in the way described.

Answer (score 25):

If you need the category Id in Magento2 ,then you can get the values using the following steps to be followed

1.Include the use `Magento\Framework\Registry` in your class file.

```
<?php
/**
 * class file
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

...
```

2.Create an object for that using object Manager or else if your using it in the controller then assign in your `__construct()` function as `\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry`:

```
...

/**
 * @var Registry
 */

class BlueLine
{
    ...
    private $registry;
    ...

    public function __construct(Registry $registry) 
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    ...
```

3.Then you can simply use it with the class as:

```
$category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');

echo $category->getId();
```

For the further Reference in Magento2 Implementation of this concept refer the class file and function called public function [**`_initCategory()`**](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Category/View.php). In this method they are registering the current category.

Comment: Hi I follow step and check result its showing   There has been an error processing your request   Object DOMDocument should be created.

Comment: Your private property is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 11):

Try this code. this will definitely help you.

```
<?php 
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category
    echo $category->getId();
    echo $category->getName();
?>
```

Comment: You should not use the object manager in your code like that. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

Comment: how to get the category name in list page? without using objectmanager?

Answer (score 7):

The above to seem correct, but I think that jumping straight to the Registry is not the best approach. Magento provides a Layer Resolver that already encapsulates that functionality. (See the TopMenu Block in the Catalog Plugins)

I suggest injecting the \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver class and using that to get the current category. Here is the code :

```
<?php

namespace FooBar\Demo\Block;

class Demo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $layerResolver;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    }
}
```

Here is what the actual *getCurrentCategory()* method does in the Resolver Class.

```
public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    $category = $this->getData('current_category');
    if ($category === null) {
        $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        if ($category) {
            $this->setData('current_category', $category);
        } else {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCurrentStore()->getRootCategoryId());
            $this->setData('current_category', $category);
        }
    }

    return $category;
}
```

As you can see, it does still use the registry but it provides a fallback in case that fails.